# How to install software in CentOS

Tags: installation, centos, yum, apt

```
apt-get install devscripts
```

What is the equivalent in centOS?

Comment: I cleared the votes to close in order to prevent this from getting migrated to ServerFault.  I *might* be able to see this being appropriate on SuperUser, but since I can definitely imagine programmers being more interested in this information than anyone else, I'm content to leave it here on SO.

Comment: [Yum Command for package managment.](http://lintut.net/20-linux-yum-yellowdog-updater-modified-commands-for-package-management/)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

CentOS uses yum (Yellowdog Updater, Modified)

```
yum install devscripts
```

Answer (score 6):

```
yum install devscripts
```